# How the object size in R are calculated?

Tags: r, memory, vector, size

```
> print(object.size(runif(1e6)),unit="Mb")
7.6 Mb
```

This gives me 7.6Mb for a vector with 1 million elements. But why? each element is 32 bit or 64 bit? I cannot add these numbers up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're 64-bit (8-byte) floating point values.  One megabyte (Mb) is 2^20 bytes (not 10^6 - see below) ... so ...

```
8*1e6/(2^20)
[1] 7.629395
```

Lots of potential for confusion about what `Mb` means:

- [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) "MB" is the recommended abbreviation for "megabyte", but R uses "Mb"
- there is [plenty of confusion](https://superuser.com/questions/373579/is-it-true-that-1-mb-can-mean-either-1000000-bytes-1024000-bytes-or-1048576-by) about whether "mega" means 10^6 or 2^20 in this context.

As usual, this is clearly documented, deep in the details of `?object.size` ...

> As illustrated by below tables, the legacy and IEC standards use *binary* units (multiples of 1024), whereas the SI standard uses *decimal* units (multiples of 1000) ...
>
> ```
> *object size*  *legacy*  *IEC*
>    1           1 bytes   1 B  
> 1024           1 Kb      1 KiB
> 1024^2         1 Mb      1 MiB
> ```

Google's conversion appears to use SI units (1 MB = 10^6 bytes) instead.

Comment: why google will give me [this calculation](https://www.google.com/search?q=1mb+to+bytes&oq=1mb+to+bytes&aqs=chrome..69i57j6j0.7223j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ?